# Aspect not executed on class from dependency

Tags: spring, aspectj

I'm trying to add an aspect on org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcOperations as explained [here](http://www.gotoquiz.com/web-coding/programming/java-programming/log-sql-statements-with-parameter-values-filled-in-spring-jdbc/) and the calls from my DAO classes to JdbcTemplate implementing JdbcOperations are not intercepted.

```
@Before("execution(* org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcOperations.*(String, ..))")
public void log(JoinPoint jp) throws Throwable
{
    ...
}
```

To try to understand if my configuration of AspectJ was corrected, I added this method to my Aspect class:

```
@Before("execution(* be.siemens.medical.dao.*DAO.*(..))")
public void hello(JoinPoint jp) throws Throwable
{
    System.out.println("HELLO ASPECT");
}
```

And this is well executed, I get the sysout.

So, is there anything specific to do in order to add aspects on classes from dependencies ?

Comment: And why do you think your class implements `JdbcOperations`... That is a spring interface which is implemented by the `JdbcTemplate`.

Comment: What I'm saying is that my class is calling JdbcTemplate, JdbcTemplate being an implementation of JdbcOperations, sorry if that was confusing

Comment: Spring will only apply AOP on Spring beans if you are creating an instance of `JdbcTemplate` yourself instead of letting the context do that it will not work.

Comment: What is your suggestion to properly instantiate it in the context ? I tried the following <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate" p:dataSource-ref="datasource" /> but this ends up with a NoSuchBeanDefinitionException which is probably due to the proxy created by the aspect.

Comment: If I put this in my context <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/> with this bean declaration <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate" p:dataSource-ref="datasource" />, the app context is properly created and the application runs but the aspect is not executed

Comment: How you enabled AOP in App context?

Comment: Like this: <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>, note that if the proxy-target-class="false", the context doesn't find a JdbcTemplate bean

Comment: I doubt if this is possible with spring AOP, you need to do something like described here http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-aj-ltw

Comment: I must admit that I don't understand why, my understanding is that load time weaving is used to be able to target any class loaded in the JVM and not only Spring beans. However here the JdbcTemplate is a Spring managed bean ?!